# Using below description How to generate PHP Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, url

Hello some one help me to generate expressions to copy url from this

```
(a) href="/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/public/Manab-Biswas&sa=U&ved=0CBIQFjAAahUKEwjp-9mu6d3HAhVOwI4KHVYFB_0&usg=AFQjCNE5q56vNDTh54PMdr1sCRgQGI7rFA">Manab Biswas Profiles | Facebook (/a)
```

Url will be like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/public/Manab-Biswas
```

Comment: be descriptive atleast!

Comment: I want to copy https://www.facebook.com/public/Manab-Biswas this link from href="/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/public/Manab-Biswas&sa=U&ved=0CBIQFjAAahUKEwjp-9mu6d3HAhVOwI4KHVYFB_0&usg=AFQjCNE5q56vNDTh54PMdr1sCRgQGI7rFA">Manab Biswas Profiles | Facebook (/a)

Comment: have a look at my answer :)

Comment: @biswasmanob you are going to have trouble getting help with the way you phrased your problem/question. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
href="\/url\?q=([^&]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wW2mQ0/1)

[image]

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

$search = "(a) href=\"/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/public/Manab-Biswas&sa=U&ved=0CBIQFjAAahUKEwjp-9mu6d3HAhVOwI4KHVYFB_0&usg=AFQjCNE5q56vNDTh54PMdr1sCRgQGI7rFA\">Manab Biswas Profiles | Facebook (/a)";
preg_match_all('/href="\/url\?q=([^&]*)/', $search, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1])


?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(44) "https://www.facebook.com/public/Manab-Biswas"
}
```

you can retrieve the link from `$matches[1][0]`

Comment: What will be pattern for preg_match_all()

Comment: $patern4='/href="\/url\?q=([^&]*)/i' it give me syntax error